# php mysql query not being sent to database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have written this function to register users on my site. it was all working fine until recently the only change i have done is added extra columns into the table could this have an effect on the way i need to write this function?

```
function register($link){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password2']);
    if($password == $password2){
        $password= md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(UserName,email,password)VALUES('$username','$email','$password')";
        mysqli_query($link,$sql);
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now registered";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: index.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Passwords do not match";
    }
}
```

Comment: from this ```'$username','$email','$password'```   I would like you to suggest php manual before doing this .

Comment: Hi coulld you elaborate? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php#comment35408611_3446245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will have an effect if the columns are set-up to be NON NULL.  If you aren't sure, you can check the table definition with `describe` in a mysql console.

Comment: Or change the column definitions to accept null values; depending on what is appropriate for your situation.